# Azure DevOps: How can i connect Testcafe-tests to a testcase?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, automated-tests

SO far i can run the pipeline manually and it runs my testcafe tests with the "node myTests.js" command.
[my pipeline run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jOzd.png)

My file myTests.js looks like this:
[myTests.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IILOH.png)

I followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops

I tried to associated an test to my Testplan via the REST API, i guess theres some problem. because i can name it whatever i want and it just runs it without errors:[my testcase association](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCgGd.png)

When i run a testcase it says it found an automated test and it runs it without errors, the VsTest Job runs but with a warning:

> 2021-05-18T09:16:32.7619103Z Source filter: ***test*.dll,!***TestAdapter.dll,!**\obj**

> 2021-05-18T09:16:32.7879061Z ##[warning]No test sources found matching the given filter '***,!**\obj**'

Any ideas what im doing wrong? I just want to run my pipeline or my test when im running a testcase in my testplans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure DevOps: How can i connect Testcafe-tests to a testcase?

I am afraid you could not connect the Testcafe-tests to a testcase at this moment.

According to the document [Run automated tests from test plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops):

> You will need:
>
> A Team Build pipeline that **generates builds containing the test
> binaries**.

That is the reason why you get the error `No test sources found matching the given filter '*test.dll,!*TestAdapter.dll,!\obj*`.

We could build and test the Testcafe-tests in the azure devops pipeline.

Please check the document [Integrate TestCafe with Azure DevOps](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402822/guides/continuous-integration/azure-devops) for some more details.